# Errors while running bookInfo example of Istio via Consul

Tags: consul, istio

I followed all the instructions to deploy Istio and the bookInfo example from the [website](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/). When I am applying the 'bookinfo.sidecars.yaml' file, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Service 'details-v1-init' uses the network stack of container 'consul_details-v1_1' which does not exist.
```

Any clues/suggestions? `docker ps` output is as below. 
Thanks.

```
# docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                             NAMES
b0e0101a3eee        istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v3:1.8.0               "/opt/ibm/docker/doc…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9080/tcp, 9443/tcp                                                                                                consul_reviews-v3_1_28883479b3a9
537541698e6d        istio/examples-bookinfo-details-v1:1.8.0               "/bin/sh -c 'ruby de…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9080/tcp                                                                                                          consul_details-v1_1_cdccfbf1a4f4
5f99a4af633e        istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v2:1.8.0               "/opt/ibm/docker/doc…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9080/tcp, 9443/tcp                                                                                                consul_reviews-v2_1_862dda9b3ebb
7168373c7151        istio/examples-bookinfo-ratings-v1:1.8.0               "/bin/sh -c 'node /o…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9080/tcp                                                                                                          consul_ratings-v1_1_36958d99bd3c
7d49f4a2756f        istio/examples-bookinfo-productpage-v1:1.8.0           "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:9081->9080/tcp                                                                                            consul_productpage-v1_1_c76939929d14
c7a48c76955c        istio/examples-bookinfo-reviews-v1:1.8.0               "/opt/ibm/docker/doc…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9080/tcp, 9443/tcp                                                                                                consul_reviews-v1_1_d5ff8edaea77
584d82ad2f9d        istio/pilot:1.0.4                                      "/usr/local/bin/pilo…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         15003/tcp, 15005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->15007/tcp                                                                     consul_pilot_1_a886d8efde70
2ea3814a9430        openzipkin/zipkin:2.7                                  "/bin/sh -c 'test -n…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9410/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9411->9411/tcp                                                                                  consul_zipkin_1_1adb4c433f62
620b53b530a9        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.7.3   "kube-apiserver --et…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                                                                            consul_istio-apiserver_1_74bc95072d1d
ab2c2f5a529b        quay.io/coreos/etcd:latest                             "/usr/local/bin/etcd…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:2379-2380->2379-2380/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4001->4001/tcp                                                          consul_etcd_1_a16aeb2d7508
529adeda3b3f        gliderlabs/consul-server                               "/bin/consul agent -…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:8400->8400/tcp, 8300-8302/tcp, 8600/tcp, 8301-8302/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 172.28.0.1:53->8600/udp   consul_consul_1_3d8dd30c0067
1846d35812e2        gliderlabs/registrator:latest                          "/bin/registrator -i…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours                                                                                                                           consul_registrator_1_cbcf37b622e7
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Thanks Bsquare for the edits. Yes, will clarify the question a bit more soon if I don't get any responses.

Answer (score 0):

`network_mode`is same as `--network` parameters for docker. So it make two container in the same network. Just like two container in the same pod while using K8S. And in docker-compose, it support a special form: "container:[container name/id]", which make the new container work with in the same network space of the old container which is specified by `container name/id`.
So you'd better update `consul_details-v1_1` in your bookinfo.sidecars.yaml into `consul_details-v1_1_cdccfbf1a4f4`, which could make sidecar container communicate with the main container. You should also update `consul_ratings-v1_1` as well as `consul_productpage-v1_1`, `consul_reviews-v1_1` and so on.